# RegExp check password 6 chars + 1 number

Tags: javascript, regex

I know this has been asked a million times, but I just can't seem to crack it.

I have this:

```
function checkPassword(strPassword)
{
  var objPattern = new RegExp("^.*(?=.{6,})(?=.*[a-z])[a-z0-9]*$");

  var blnResult = objPattern.test(strPassword);
  return(blnResult)
}
```

...but it only seems to check the length, and not if there's a number?

What have I missed?

Edit:

The number can be anywhere in the string, not necessarily at the end.

Comment: You mispositioned the lookaheads, put them right after `^` and decide what you need to match: `.*` or `[a-z0-9]*`.  Do you allow any chars or just letters/digits?

Comment: What about that [a-z]{6}[0-9]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep it simple: `if(strPassword.length >= 6 && /\d/.test(strPassword))` will do the work and is way more readable

Comment: You know it might be totally different from what OP needs, right? There are two mutually excluding consuming patterns in OP regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew if the title is correct (*check password 6 chars + 1 number*) I don't see any issue with the solution I provided. Am I wrong?

Comment: Nice and simple. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can just include both tests separately in your function:

```
function checkPassword(strPassword){
  var blnResult = /\w{6,}/.test(strPassword)
   && /\d+/.test(strPassword);
  return(blnResult)
}
```

**Demo:**

```js
function checkPassword(strPassword){
  var blnResult = /\w{6,}/.test(strPassword)
   && /\d+/.test(strPassword);
  return(blnResult)
}

var passwords = ["zeaezee2reer", "sds2", "ssdsdsdsdsd", "12155"];
passwords.forEach(function(p){
 console.log(p+" ::: "+ checkPassword(p));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need exactly 6 characters plus 1 number then you can use **^[A-z]{6}[0-9]{1}$** or like atleast 6 characters and atleast 1 number then use **^[A-z]{6,}[0-9]{1,}$**